# Apache Ignite vs GridGain?

Tags: ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain, in-memory-data-grid

I can't understand for difference between Apache Ignite and GridGain platform. They are equals? Or GridGain is a standard that implemented by Apache Ignite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the website](https://www.gridgain.com/technology/apache-ignite):

> Apache® Ignite™ was originally contributed to the Apache Software Foundation by GridGain Systems. The project rapidly evolved into a top level Apache project with tens of thousands of downloads per month. The GridGain Professional Edition, Enterprise Edition, and Ultimate Edition are built on Apache Ignite.

Enterprise and Ultimate editions have some "enterprise" features that are not in the open source version.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, Gridgain is wraper built on top of Ignite. 
Gridgain gives you additional features such as Security, Rolling production update etc that is required for enterprise level application.

you may find the full list here

https://www.gridgain.com/products/gridgain-vs-ignite